# rotate a transparent gif using imagemagick

Tags: rotation, imagemagick, transparent, gif

I am going to rotate a gif image with transparent color. But after the rotation, the image loses the transparency and has a non-transparent background. How could I do it correctly with both transparent color and transparent background?

Here is my command:

```
convert test.gif -alpha set -rotate 30 -background transparent rotate.gif
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use "-background none".  Like so:

```
convert -background none -rotate 30 test.gif rotate.gif
```

This should preserve any transparency in your original image, while making the extra canvas real estate that isn't covered by your original image transparent as well.

Comment: Hello, my result looks like this: -> [gifRotate](http://52.87.29.120/storage/temp/tDGzZc_gifRotare_60_bJYtQatororo-2.gif), but the original gif is this->[GifOriginal](https://i2.wp.com/www.zupi.pixelshow.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/tororo-2.gif), help me